# Should there be a tag for death saves?

Tags: discussion, tags

I just asked [this question about death saves](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/205510/do-the-speed-factor-rules-affect-when-death-saves-should-be-rolled) and noticed there is no tag for death saves.

It seems to me as though such a tag would be useful. It is an important concept in multiple versions of D&D and a quick search showed that there are over 1,400 posts that contain the term.

I am therefore wondering:

- **Should there be a tag for the term?**
- **If not, should questions like mine be tagged [character-death](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character-death), [saving-throw](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/saving-throw), or both?**

Comment: Technically, they're called "death saving throws"... And there are already tags for [tag:character-death] and [tag:saving-throw].

Answer (score 5):

#### "Death saving throws" are just another saving throw

This specific kind of saving throws has a few unique rules and such, but in the end it's just another saving throw, which falls under the tag of the same name. If we were to make a tag for every mechanic that is part of a larger category, but with a few specific rules for it, there would be no end to the tags which need to be created (which would pretty much defeat the point of tags in the first place).

As such, I believe the tag [saving-throw](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/saving-throw) should do the trick, just like it currently does for other saving throws. As a matter of fact, it would even make sense to edit this tag's description to include those throws, as just about every other kind of throw is listed there.

Comment: This seems like the best approach. The search “[saving-throw] death” ([link](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bsaving-throw%5D+death)) is both intuitive and sufficient for finding questions about death saving throws. If searching for questions about death saves required obscure search terms, I’d say there might be a good reason for a tag, but that search is really easy to come up with.

Answer (score 0):

### Make a new tag

If we only had to contend with D&D, I might say that the combination of [character-death](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character-death) and [saving-throw](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/saving-throw) is enough even though I'm generally opposed to saying "use these two tags together to mean something specific". However, D&D isn't the only system which has some kind of "near death" mechanic, and those systems don't necessarily use saving throws. As an example, Goblin Laws of Gaming (or at least the "Many rats on sticks" version of it which I've played) has "Fatal Wounds" which occur at negative HP, and the mechanics for surviving a fatal wound are substantially different from the game's "saves".

I'm not sure if the tag should just be [death-saves](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/death-saves) with the assumption that the D&D term will be most recognizable, or something more generic like [near-death](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/near-death).